# shiny interactive plot coordinate issues with lattice(Extra)

Tags: shiny

I try to use the interactive plot, esp. `click` functionality to identify points in a plot. While it works fine with base `plot`, it doesn't identify the coordinates correctly in `lattice::xyplot`, thus failing to return the appropriate row from the `data.frame`.

A simple example:

```
library(shiny)
library(latticeExtra)
ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot",click="plot_click"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,verbatimTextOutput("click_info")),
    column(4,verbatimTextOutput("click_pt"))
  )
)
)
server=shinyServer(function(input,output){
  output$plot=renderPlot(xyplot(NOx~C,data=ethanol))  # this fail
  # output$plot=renderPlot(plot(NOx~C,data=ethanol))   # this works
  output$click_info=renderPrint(input$plot_click)
  output$click_pt=renderPrint(nearPoints(ethanol,input$plot_click,"C","NOx"))
})
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

A perhaps remotely related post is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494233/raw-scaling-of-interactive-shiny-plot).
Any help?